# Change the data values getting from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, express, sequelize.js

I am using express, sequelize and SQL Server for my project.

I have three tables and I must read columns from these data tables.

My first database table looks like this:

[image]

In the first query, I select the Value columns

```
SELECT Date_Time, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 
FROM S001T01
```

Actually I must read the all columns but problem starting here, all status code holding in different table with different code names such as ,
(StatusList Table)

[image]

When I receive post request I must send the response with

```
Value1,Status1,Value2,Status2....
```

But, replace the values ​​in the status column with the equivalents in the statuslist table. For example, it should write "Veri Yok" (it means no data in turkish) instead of 0.

I thought of writing a query separately for each column and changing it in the array, but I think it will take a lot of time.

I tried to write

```
SELECT 
    Status1,
    Status2,  
    CASE Status1
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Veri YOK'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Veri Geçerli'
    END
FROM S001T01
```

but I have 110 StatusCodeName, it is hard to write for every column and every code.

Is there any other way to change all column data?

I would be glad if you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are working from a bad table design so here are some options:

1. Since you have 8 values, join to your Statuslist table eight times

```
SELECT Date_Time, Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7, Value8 
sl1.StatusUseCode as Status1, ...... sl8.StatusUseCode as Status8,
FROM S001T01 s
left join StatusList sl1 on s.Status1=sl1.StatusCode
left join StatusList sl2 on s.Status2=sl2.StatusCode
left join StatusList sl3 on s.Status3=sl3.StatusCode
             :
             :
left join StatusList sl8 on s.Status8=sl8.StatusCode
```

2. The other option is a bit fancier

a. Pivot columns to rows

b. Join to StatusList

c. Pivot back to columns

Comment: I've been dealing with this for hours. It helped a lot. You are great !! Thank you

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)